# LocalDB: create db from existing SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, localdb

Just wondering if there's a quick way of creating a new localdb from an existing SQL Server database. The idea is to reproduce the "real" db structure in order to run some integration tests from the VSTS during a CI build.

Currently, I'm using the Generate Scripts option to get the SQL for creating the required db objects, but unfortunately it needs some cleaning before it can be run against a new localdb.

Is there an alternative approach for this kind of work?

Thanks,

Luis

Comment: Your current method is the most reasonable, I think.

Comment: Restore a backup?

Comment: Oh well, it looks I'll still need to keep editing the generated scripts by hand then...thanks